# How can I optimize my MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, typo3

I have 3,066,691 queries logged and some red numbers in my phpmyadmin status information:

- Slow_queries  24
- Innodb_buffer_pool_reads  2,2 M
- Innodb_log_waits  8
- Innodb_row_lock_time_avg  49
- Innodb_row_lock_waits     1
- Created_tmp_disk_tables   21

There are also green numbers in phpmyadmin but I don't know what they mean ? I use Typo3 and MySQL.

Comment: Not a programming question. Best asked on [dba.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MySQL Tunin Primer Script](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) was helpfull for me. It gives some helpfull hints and shows which values are good, which one bad.
For TYPO3 i guess, some slow_queries are no problem, the will probably occur only in the backend.

Comment: What does the red and the green numbers means?

Comment: green: good values, red: bad values. But as allways: it depends how good and how bad. You should not have slow_queries at all, but some task in TYPO3 (like import/export) can lead to slow_queries. But 24 out of 3066691 is no problem. And if you have too much free space, it could be green but it would be a waste of free space then. So, do not rely to much on the colors.