# Optimum php.ini and my.cnf settings for a small Drupal 7 site on a virtual server

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I looking for advice on how to set up the default configuration of php.ini and my.cnf for a small site (100 pages) with very little traffic (300 visitors per day). All pages have a bit of text, some images, no video, no audio, no flash/silverlight, very little javascript and jquery. For tracking I'm using GA and Piwik. The main site database is around 50MB.

The site is hosted on a virtual server with 20GB RAM and 6 vCPUs so there's hopefully a lot of muscle to make it run very fast.

I don't know much about tweaking php and mysql settings and would appreciate it if your answers can be as detailed as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the 20GB RAM? This wouldn't be your average virtual machine server, I'd suspect, and I really doubt you'd need more than about 4 GB of RAM for the scenario described.

Comment: Its actually a "hybrid server" from heart internet and 20GB RAM is the minimum you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special configuration. Your server is so severely oversized for the task that it really hurts. Any cheap webhosting offer with some PHP and database would suffice, given your access numbers are correct.

If you really grow into areas where your server shows signs of overload, your problems will be so special that any general advice on configuration given today is wrong.

Just follow the recommended default settings for production servers for PHP 5.4 and MySQL, unless you use software that needs them different and states so in its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tune php.ini and my.cnf that much. You can run mysql tuning primer script: [How can I optimize my MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783472/how-can-i-optimize-my-mysql-server) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820933/ive-run-mysql-tuning-primer-but-i-cant-understand-it but it's difficult to understand. I would suggest to enable slow_query log and examine slow queries. I also suggest to install nginx or lighttpd and fastcgi (php-cgi) with eaccelerator. It's much faster and easier to configure. There are some interesting lighttpd parameter. When you can get a kvm virtualization to get access to the kernel parameters. I also suggest to compile php yourself and configure php to your needs. When you use php from repository I don't think you can get every php configure killswitch as module.  Also enable http compression and http cache headers. When you have 20 GB ram install a ramdisk and move temporary folders to the ramdisk.